# ngShow Animation Flicker in Safari/Moz using Angular 1.3.15

Tags: css, angularjs, css-animations, ng-animate, ng-show

I am working on an Angular 1.3.15 app that has a panel that slides in from right to left. The animation works on all browsers but on Safari and Mozilla, the panel flickers on screen and then the animation engages. It is a quick millisecond show of the panel (seemingly with the correct animation) then the proper animation engages and the panel slides in. On Safari, some ng-show events have the flicker and some do not - these are never the same on refresh. Moz is a consistent flicker on all ng-show events. Below is the CSS I am using. Thanks in advance.

```
    /* Show */
    &.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {

    -webkit-animation: 175ms slideInRight; 
    animation: 175ms slideInRight; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.865, 0.395, 0.750, 1); /* older webkit */
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.865, 0.395, 0.750, 1.205); 
    -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.865, 0.395, 0.750, 1.205); 
    -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.865, 0.395, 0.750, 1.205); 
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.865, 0.395, 0.750, 1.205);     /* custom */  

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    perspective: 1000;    
    visibility: hidden !important;
    z-index: 1;

  }

  /* Hide */
  &.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
    -webkit-animation: 175ms slideOutRight; 
    animation: 175ms slideOutRight; 

    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.865, 0.395, 0.750, 1); /* older webkit */
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.865, 0.395, 0.750, 1.205); 
    -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.865, 0.395, 0.750, 1.205); 
    -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.865, 0.395, 0.750, 1.205); 
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.865, 0.395, 0.750, 1.205); /* custom */ 
    visibility: visible !important;

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    perspective: 1000;
  }

/* ********************************************
SLIDE IN LEFT TO RIGHT
******************************************** */
@-webkit-keyframes slideInRight {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes slideInRight {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like this behavior is a bug between Angular 1.3 and Safari/Moz. I have been able to minimize it, but it still happens sometimes.

Comment: Is there any solution to this?